# cant find package Multiplayer HLAPI in pakckage manager in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

i didn't find halpi package.

[image]
[image]

i can't find halpi package in package manager.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [UNet and the HLAPI are deprecated](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001252086-UNet-Deprecation-FAQ) .. there is now [Netcode for GameObject](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/installation/upgrade_from_UNet).

And then you are looking at the packages that already are installed in the project.

To view all available packages change the [`Packages` drop-down](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-filter.html) from `In Project` to `Unity Registry`